# WebRequest POST returns “The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.”

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using WebRequest to POST a file through a console application to an server in my organisation. After some research on-line,  I was able to come up with the code below;

```
try
{
    RegisterString("Uploading encrypted file to server....Please wait!!");
    string url = @"http://localhost:3333/MySite/"
    string filepath = @"C:\test.txt";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_username, ftp_password);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filePath);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;


    //Here is the Business end of the code...
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    //and here is the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    RegisterString("File uploaded sucessfully");                

    try
    {
        //Delete file after transmission
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        RegisterString(ex.Message);
    }

    WriteToLog("End");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    RegisterString(ex.Message);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    WriteToLog("End");
}
```

However I get the exception "405 Method Not Allowed". Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Since the response explicitly complains about the *Method* - did you already try `request.Method = "GET";` (instead of "POST")?

Comment: Though I think this has a lot more to do with the code at the other end of your operation, the mime type for HTTP POSTs with binary data is usually `multipart/form-data`. It is possible that the service you're posting to isn't expecting a standard kind of form post, but still I would expect your content type should be whatever the actual format of the data is, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: once I changed the contenttype to multipart/form-data. It throws another error (404) file not found)

Answer (score 0):

Is it an ftp server? If so the method should be PUT, not POST.

Comment: its a webserver...and I'm using put. Here's a sample: WebClient client = new WebClient(); CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();

                        credCache.Add(new Uri(@ftp_url + filePath), "Basic",
                        new NetworkCredential(ftp_username, ftp_password, "africa"));
                        client.Credentials = credCache;  Uri address = new Uri(@ftp_url + filePath);
                WriteToLog(@ftp_url + filePath);

                byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(address,"PUT", filePath);